# SQL Server Query Performance Issue: Need Replacement of NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance, not-exists

Could someone optimitize the performance of below General SQL Query:

```
select fn.column1 
from dbo.function1(input1) as fn
where (not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 
                   where fn.column1 = t1.column1) 
       and not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 
                       where fn.column1 = t2.column1))
```

For the above query, consider the approximate row count given below.

1. `select fn.column1 from dbo.function1(input1) as fn` -- returns 64000 records in 2 seconds.
2. table 1 (Column1) record-- returns 3000 records  -- 1 second
3. table 2 (Column1) record-- returns 2000 records  -- 1 second

So, if I run each select statement, it pulls and displays record in 1 or 2 seconds. But, if I run the full query, it takes more than a minute to display 64000 - (3000 + 2000) = 59000 records.

I tried the using `EXCEPT` like this:

```
 select fn.column1 
 from dbo.function1(input1) 

 except 

 (select column1 from dbo.table1 union select column1 from dbo.table2)
```

Nothing improves my performance. Same it takes a minute to display 59000 records. This is with the same case for "NOT IN" Scenario.

Also I noticed that if we use UNION, instead of EXCEPT in the above query, it returns 59K records in 2 seconds.

**UPDATED:**

The function (a bit complex) contains the below pseudocode

```
select column1, column2,...column6 
from dbo.table1 
inner join dbo.table2 
inner join ....
inner join dbo.table6 
inner join dbo.innerfunction1 
where <Condition 1>

UNION ALL

select column1, column2,...column6 
from dbo.table1 
inner join dbo.table2 
inner join ...
inner join dbo.table4 
inner join dbo.innerfunction2 
where (condition 2)
```

Assume that two inner functions has single table select statement

My question is: if I select the column from the function, it displays 64K records in 1 sec. But, if the whole query executed, it takes more than a minute.

[Please Note: This query need to be used in function]

Could any one help me to improve this?

Kindly let me know if you need more details or clarifications.

Regards,
Viswa V.

Comment: Can you show the code for `dbo.function1`? It might be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the update Felix. Kindly see UPDATED: section

Comment: `if the function troubles, how the result retrieved in 1 second if I run the select statement of the function and not the whole query does?` please try to re-phrase that sentence because it is utterly unclear.

Comment: Updated! Please check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit hard to optimize without data to play with. A fiddle would be good. Nonetheless here is an approach that may work.
Create a temp table, index it then do the EXCEPT as follows:

```
SELECT
  fn.column1
INTO
  #temp  
FROM
  dbo.function1(input1) AS fn

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [temp_index] ON #temp 
(
    column1 ASC
)

SELECT
  column1
FROM
  #temp AS t
EXCEPT
(
  SELECT
    column1
  FROM
    dbo.table1
  UNION
  SELECT
    column1
  FROM
    dbo.table2
)
```

I would be interested in the result.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the update. I need to use the query in a function.

Comment: Hi JOhn. This works perfectly. But I nee to put this in a function :( . any suggestions please!

Comment: Hi @salaiviswa, Unfortunately you cannot use temporary tables (# tables) in a function. You could use a table variable but you cannot create an index on a table variable (except a primary key which may be OK if your values in column1 are unique). Your only choice is to encapsulate this code in a stored procedure instead of a function.

Comment: Hi John.. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the update. I agree what you said.